# How to convert an ASCII trace generated by ftrace to a .dat one?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, trace, ftrace

I have a ASCII trace named `trace` and I'd like to convert it to a `.dat` in order to analyze it with `kernelshark` (I cannot change tool such as `TraceCompass`, I am constrained to kernelshark).

These two tools of `trace-cmd` frontend are somehow similar to what I need:

> trace-cmd-report - show in ASCII a trace created by trace-cmd record

Actually, I need the opposite.

I know that `trace-cmd extract` generates a `.dat` file from an existing trace, but it does it by re-reading the kernel ringbuffer (where tracing info are stored) and not from a ASCII trace.

Answer (score 0):

tldr; there is not an automated tool to do it.

You need to (i) mastering the syntax of a `trace.dat` file and (ii) writing your own binary parser that reads the .dat data and convert them into ASCII format.